# Docusign Setting "iat" parameter in C# (docusign-csharp-client)

Tags: docusignapi

Currently DocuSign client is setting current system time as "iat" parameter. This causes issue when system time is not correct. As this is not required parameter from DocuSign, We would like to know how to set it to null ? Is there a way to achieve it in docusign-csharp-client?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out. This is not the recommended practice. The bigger question that should be addressed here is why the system time is not correct and what can be done to correct it.